# Unable to install webtorrent-hybrid - node-pre-gyp: command not found

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to install webtorrent-hybrid to build an electron p2p app. I'm using vue ui because the app will use vue to manage front-end stuff and I've successfully created a new project that use vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder rc-6, Vue 3 and node v15.4.0. The Electron version installed by the vue cli plugin is 11.0. Anyway When I try to install webtorrent-hybrid I always get this error in terminal

```js
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/dev/Sites/wtorrent-electron/node_modules/wrtc
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/download-prebuilt.js
npm ERR! /bin/sh: node-pre-gyp: command not found

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dev/.npm/_logs/2021-03-26T16_40_51_717Z-debug.log
command failed: npm install --loglevel error webtorrent-hybrid --legacy-peer-deps
```

Is there a way to fix it so I can install the library? If isn't possible to solve the problem, is there any alternative to use webtorrent inside an electron app?

Answer (score 1):

Try Node 14 (current lts) which has better prebuilts and if not, using the command `npm install --unsafe-perm=true` should do the trick.

Comment: need to test the second option, I don't want to downgrade only for a single library ;)

Answer (score 1):

I run first this

```
npm i -g @mapbox/node-pre-gyp
```

And after this I ran

```
npm i webtorrent-hybrid
```

and it worked